# Creating a one-off branch in Github with Eclipse + EGit ( in FlashBuilder)

Tags: eclipse, git, github, flash-builder, egit

**My set up:** Using Eclipse-based Flash Builder (Adobe product) which uses EGit.

I've got a client project up on gitHub and I've been working with it pretty well. There is the Master and then I created a "Develop" branch on Github. I have a local git version of the "Develop" branch – which I branch, work on, then merge to the GitHub "Develop" branch, and finally commit to Master.

*(I know I am describing this badly – I looked at a bunch of tutorials and I think I have things basically set up correctly – but I am still new enough with Git that I am anxious about losing everything if I screw something up)*

**My Question** I have been asked by the client to do a one-off version of their product with some changes which will not be merged to "Master" and I am wondering how I do this.

- do I create a new branch on gitHub and then import that into a new Flash Builder project? (so I have two separate versions of the client's project in my local git directory)
- do I create a new branch on gitHub, rebase my local version to that branch, make the changes, etc. and when done, rebase my local version back to the regular "Develop" branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your first bullet point is correct. Although I don't believe you have to re-import this into a new Flash Builder project. Creating a new branch with git is seamless and easy.

Assuming you are on branch `develop`, just do:

`git checkout -b my_new_branch`

If you want to push that to your remote so that other people can see it just do:

`git push -u origin my_new_branch`

when you want to switch back to develop:

`git checkout develop`

and if you get to a point where you want to merge my_new_branch into develop just do this from the feature branch:

`git merge my_new_branch`

Comment: So are you saying if I create a new local branch ("my_new_branch"), work on it, I can then push it to github – and it will appear there as "my_new_branch"? (I am a little phobic about messing up and wiping out my entire git repository ;-)

Comment: Yes. You will not mess up your other branch at all. That's the beauty of git, it's so easy to create other branches and your master branch stays intact. You can always check which branch your currently on by typing ``git branch`` or ``git status``

Comment: Feels good right? Harness the power of Git and now practice: http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/